# While using pull we are getting a path error

Tags: git, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

PS C:\Merchant\merchant-app> git pull
error: invalid path 'c:UsersUSER_NAMEupload-keystore.jks'

The error is from some path we didn't know where its come from.

Comment: Please check your path of storeFile in key.properties

Comment: Does `git config --list` have a config with a value referring to `upload-keystore.jks`?

Answer (score 0):

I am fetch similar problem, trying to checkout a repository from GitHub that contained files with a ":" in the name, on a Windows.

Please run git config `core.protectNTFS false` solved issue, but only if You took some steps before and after running it. The entire process went like so:

1. Clone the Git repository locally
2. 'cd' into the local Git repository folder that has just been cloned
3. Run `git reset`
4. Run `git config core.protectNTFS false`
5. Run `git checkout`